# Is it possible to use AVG function to give the average of 2 results from within a sub-query that has a UNION?

Tags: postgresql, subquery, average, union

So I have written a UNION query and then, in order to amalgamate the 2 averages from both sides of the union, I have put the whole union query inside a select query and given it an alias, this isn't the whole thing, but gets the point across I think(?):

```
select supplier, year, month, avg(average) as average from

(select supplier, year, month, avg(age(tableA.date, tableB.date)) as 
average
from tableA join tableB using(supplier)
group by supplier, year, month

UNION ALL

select supplier, year, month, avg(age(tableC.date, tableB.date)) as 
average
from tableC join tableB using(supplier)
group by supplier, year, month
) as x
group by supplier, year, month
```

I have a Maths graduate telling me that you simply can't average an average, but having looked at the data I think that the outer query is treating the average from the inner query as a single amount of time for each inner query and is therefore allowing me to average it outside as though it hasn't already been averaged, if that makes any kind of sense??

Any perspectives on this very welcome.

Comment: The inner query gives you two rows per combination of `supplier, year, month` and so the average of the outer query is essentially the average from the first union part plus the one from the second divided by two (for each `supplier, year, month`)

Comment: Thanks a_horse_with_no_name ,  So, you agree, that there is no reason why it shouldn't work?  Also, FYI, when a record doesn't exist for a given month in one of the tables for a particular supplier the average is, obviously, the result of that one record; this happens frequently and is why I didn't simply do a divide by 2 and wanted to use the AVG function in the outside query.

Comment: I do not think your math grad was saying your query would not run - it will as there is nothing syntactically wrong. However, I think what they were saying is that *taking the average of averages is mathematically incorrect* thus your result is incorrect. Your result is a value based on a false premise. For example using integers let A be the set {20, 15, 35, 82, 103}, and B the set {15, 12, 6}. AVG(A)=51, AVG(B)=11, AVG( avg(A), avg(B)) = 31, but AVG(20, 15, 35, 82, 10315, 12, 6} = 26.375.